# Settings for Devise::Mailer - diaspora smtp_envelope_from and smtp_envelope_to sendmail

Tags: devise, sendmail, actionmailer, mailer, diaspora

I am having a similar problem. I am using the sendmail option and continue to get the error

> "An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message
>   smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address."

I have tested the Mail gem from the ruby console and it works perfect. AppConfig reports that delivery method is sendmail and also reports that `sender_address` is exactly as entered in the `app/config/diaspora.yaml` file. `Mail.delivery_method` also returns sendmail. When I set `@smtp_envelope_from = 'myemail@example.com'` in `gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb` I get a similar yet different error message..

> "An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message
>   smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address."

this error comes up in `lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:9:in check_delivery_params'`, I thus attempt to set the `@smtp_envelope_to = 'myrecipient@example.com'` in `message.rb`, just to test this as I know these settings should be applied somewhere else (this thread seems to be the only I can find addressing this) the error I receive after setting the `@smtp_envelope_to` is

> undefined methodmap' for "myrecipient@example.com":String

I was originally concerned that the `delivery_method` wasn't being set right but the trace shows that before check_delivery_params is called I enter `lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/sendmail.rb:50:in`deliver!' so that is not the case. This is a standard install cloned a week or so ago. Using `RVM and ruby-1.9.3-p484`. I get the same errors in production mode and development mode. I am using strategies like `grep -r` method signature to help me find files and attributes where they are being set and initialized. I am having trouble understanding how configurate sets the values in `AppConfig`
 and exactly how `Devise::Mailer` works.

My greatest inquisition in all of this is where in the diaspora application do I call the methods to set `smtp_envelope_from` and `smtp_envelope_to`, what is the standard way of setting these in diaspora, and how do I confirm they are set. I am trying to acquire a succesfull mail for `password_instructions`. It seems this is left up to devise to handle.

Please help as I have been hunting around for the solution for some time. I am not ready to give up on `sendmail` as that is not necessarily the problem. Also in the version I am working with `config/initializers/devise.rb` does not have the attributes mentioned previously, they seem to be automatically set somehow, this however good for separating data from logic is actually a little annoying when it doesn't seem to be working.

Further: research
I issue the following commands to see where the attributes in question are set and it does not return a single file where they are set to the values I would expect them to be, they are initialized thats it.

> ~$ grep -r smtp_envelope_from
>
> .irb-history:Mail.smtp_envelope_from
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:      if mail.smtp_envelope_from.blank?
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:        raise ArgumentError.new('An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address.')
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:      [mail.smtp_envelope_from, mail.smtp_envelope_to, message]
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:      @smtp_envelope_from = nil
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_from = 'Mikel '
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_from #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_from 'Mikel '
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_from #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    def smtp_envelope_from( val = nil )
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:        self.smtp_envelope_from = val
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:        @smtp_envelope_from || return_path || sender || from_addrs.first
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_from = 'Mikel '
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_from #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    def smtp_envelope_from=( val )
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:      @smtp_envelope_from = val

The other command I run to see what I can find

> ~$ grep -r smtp_envelope_to
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:      if mail.smtp_envelope_to.blank?
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:        raise ArgumentError.new('An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.')
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:      [mail.smtp_envelope_from, mail.smtp_envelope_to, message]
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:      @smtp_envelope_to = nil
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to = 'Mikel '
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to ['Mikel ', 'Lindsaar ']
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to #=> ['mikel@test.lindsaar.net', 'lindsaar@test.lindsaar.net']
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    def smtp_envelope_to( val = nil )
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:        self.smtp_envelope_to = val
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:        @smtp_envelope_to || destinations
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to = 'Mikel '
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to = ['Mikel ', 'Lindsaar ']
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    #  mail.smtp_envelope_to #=> ['mikel@test.lindsaar.net', 'lindsaar@test.lindsaar.net']
>   .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:    def smtp_envelope_to=( val )
>
> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:      @smtp_envelope_to =
>
> grep: aquota.user: Permission denied
>
> diaspora/log/development.log:ArgumentError (An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.):
>
> diaspora/log/development.log:ArgumentError (An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.):
>
> grep: lost+found: Permission denied

As you can see these settings are initialized in `mail/lib/mail/message.rb` but are not given appropriate values anywhere else. Is it possible the methods could have an alias name or be set somehow that I could not find them using this technique? Is it possible the `actionmailer` and `mail` in `ruby-1.9.3-p848` have newer requirements or changes that diaspora doesn't support? (the installation wiki says specifically to use this version.) The `config/diaspora.yaml` allows me to specify the default from address but the to address should be set in the mail block if I am not mistaken

Still at a loss on this please help

Yet further testing in response to error

> undefined methodmap' for "myrecipient@example.com":String

`lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:9:in check_delivery_params'` was expecting an array so I set @smptp_envelope_to = ['myreciepient@example.com'] in `gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb` and the email was a success when requesting the password_reset_instructions, but the content in the email was empty. Now considering a problem somewhere in `~/diaspora/app/mailers/diaspora_devise_mailer.rb` or `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@diaspora/gems/devise-3.0.2/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb` when I cat the last mentioned file I get

```
> class Devise::Mailer < Devise.parent_mailer.constantize
>>  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers
>>
>>  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
>>>    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
>>  end

>>  def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
>>>    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
>>  end

>>  def unlock_instructions(record, opts={})
>>>    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
>>  end
> end
```

I am now working my way through the controllers in the `devise/app` at this point I believe the problem is with devise. Hashing over the howto's on mailers in ruby should help me locate this problem. A message block must be created somewhere but it's location is not obvious. If anyone can point me to the right place to create the message block I will do a small victory dance or not.

I also want to note the only entry in ~/diaspora/config/routes.rb relating to this is

```
>  # This is a hack to overide a route created by devise.
>  # I couldn't find anything in devise to skip that route, see Bug #961
>  match 'users/edit' => redirect('/user/edit')
>
>  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations",
>                                      :password      => "devise/passwords",
>                                      :sessions      => "sessions"}
```

I am curious if I shouldn't take a look at this bug in diaspora

This has been magically fixed by cloning diaspora from github again. It was a newer version that also required a newer version of ruby. Went through the standard process and everything works. Thank you for looking at this. I am still going to keep digging, see whats different and stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by cloning an updated version of diaspora. The issue appeared to be that a newer version of Devise::Mailer broke diaspora.